# Bootstrap 4 jacked up on IE 10

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am starting to regret moving to B4. I am already trying to troubleshoot my nav in IE 10 which is based on their example:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/jumbotron/

When I look at it on IE 10, the nav floats off the viewport edge - see search button at top right:

[image]

Isn't it supposed to work on IE10+ ?

Comment: Yes, they clearly state `On Windows, we support Internet Explorer 10-11 / Microsoft Edge`, so please delete your question, nothing to answer, not about coding, off topic etc.

Comment: The `navbar` component in Bootstrap 4 deviates significantly in some ways from Bootstrap 3. Are you sure this isn't just an issue of improper migration, as opposed to an IE10 flaw in the implementation?  We can't address that since you haven't shared your code...

Comment: I didn't migrate from 3, just started out fresh with B4 using their example template. 
If they state it works on B4, what is wrong with their own example in IE10?

Comment: Hmmm...you are right, in IE10 it doesnt seem to be working: https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/761551d14b6c4b39783267afdeee109a2743bd01/win7_ie_10.0.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to download the working version of B4-dev from git, not form the bootstrap website.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that I would keep in mind:

1. Twitter-Bootstrap v4 is still in Beta. If this is truly a bug, then I would report it to the developers.
2. The navbar component was redesigned completely around the flexbox. According to [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), IE10 (and 11) only have partial support for the flexbox.
3. There is also this quote on the Browsers and Devices page:

> Please be aware that some CSS3 properties and HTML5 elements are not fully supported in IE10, or require prefixed properties for full functionality.

And just mulling through the CSS for v4, it doesn't appear as though any of the IE10 CSS prefixes are there.

Comment: I reported it as a bug, but it was closed as "The issue isn't present in v4-dev."  - That doesn't help me. I downloaded the latest code from them. Where is the latest if that has been fixed?

Comment: The CDN provided by CDNJS ~should be~ the most up-to-date version, it is the same one that they provide to codepen: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: The response I got on git: "Either clone the repo and get the v4-dev branch or download the zip file. All this will be redundant when beta-2 is released, hopefully in the next days." I shell wait for the beta-2.